# Ansible: Get number of hosts in group

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get the number of hosts of a certain group.

Imagine an inventory file like this:

```
[maingroup]
server-[01:05]
```

Now in my playbook I would like to get the number of hosts that are part of `maingroup` which would be `5` in this case and store that in a variable which is supposed to be used in a template in one of the playbook's tasks.

At the moment I'm setting the variable manually which is far from ideal..

```
vars:
  HOST_COUNT: 5
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
  vars:
    HOST_COUNT: "{{ groups['maingroup'] | length }}"
```

Comment: fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'maingroup'"}

Comment: 'maingroup' has to exist in your inventory file.  in the posted example they define 'maingroup' but by default you will probably want to check the 'all' group.  see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/intro_inventory.html#default-groups

Comment: Am getting syntax errors: 
TASK with no name:

#Count the hosts in groups in inventory
      - hosts: localhost
        gather_facts: false
        vars:
          GPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_gpu_nodes'] | length }}"
          CPU_COUNT: "{{ groups['k8s_cpu_nodes'] | length }}"
        tasks:
          - assert:
              that:
                - "GPU_COUNT | int <= 1"
                - "CPU_COUNT | int <= 1"

ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <type 'bool'>


The offending  to be:

#Count the hosts in groups in inventory
      - hosts: localhost
        ^ here

Answer (score 28):

Also without explicit group name:

```
vars:
    HOST_COUNT: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | length }}"
```

Comment: This answer works in every case, unlike the selected one

Comment: can you paste the whole task syntax am getting errors.

Comment: @AhmFM, to answer I need your use case.

Comment: Read the question again. `ansible_play_hosts` is totally different from counting hosts in a group.