# Ansible create var from hosts

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to create a env var list of hosts and ports to be used for a database connection string.

The application requires two vars: a host list and a port list and uses that to create a connection string.

```
hosts: 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1
ports: 123,123,123
```

host and port are matched based on index postion.

I am able to get hosts and join them as required. What I am unable to do is dynamically create a ports string based on the number of hosts. We are currently using the same port so it should be easier.

What I would like to do is create ports:123,123,123 where the number of times 123 is repeated is equal to the number of hosts.

Looked at this link for gettingnumber of hsots: [Ansible: Get number of hosts in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310633/ansible-get-number-of-hosts-in-group)
How i just need to print 123 that numebr of times and assign it to ports.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `sequence` plugin

```
vars:
  hosts: ['127.0.0.1','127.0.0.1','127.0.0.1']

- name: ports fact with size of hosts
  set_fact:
    ports: "{{ ports | default([]) + [123]}}"
  with_sequence: count="{{ hosts | length }}"

- debug: msg="{{ ports }}"
```

> ```
>  TASK [debug] ********************* ok: [localhost] => {
>      "ports": [
>          123, 
>          123, 
>          123
>      ] }
> ```

Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/sequence.html